# Gnome dock icons remain after closing program

Tags: 20.04, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gsettings

When I close a program, the program's icon on my dock will remain for a few seconds. In the included image, I've closed Terminal, but it hasn't removed the icon from my dock yet.

How can I make the icon immediately go away after I close a program?

[image: example of remaining terminal window]

Comment: Right click on the icon and select **Remove from Favorites**.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It's not that. They're not favorited, and if they were favorited, they wouldn't go away after a few seconds, they'd stay on my dock until I unfavorite them.

Comment: I haven't seen such a behavior before. Maybe it is a buggy Gnome extension. Can you try with a freshly created user?

Comment: Ah, it works fine on a new user! If it's rare, I'll reinstall and see if that fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @Makusu2 overkill to reinstall if it is a user configuration issue. Try debugging your account. Start with disabling all Gnome Shell extensions and see if the issue is gone (log out and back in after disabling). If yes, then reenable them one by one to see when the issue reappears.

Comment: Try to move or remove the extension directories under `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/` and test by re-login.

Comment: I don't have any extensions D:
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell` has no `extensions` subdirectory

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I have reproduction steps!!!
on a new user: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false`, then, remove all your favorites on the bar (do this programatically with `dconf write /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps '@as []'`). Log out, and log back in, and you should get the bug. Most important part is that when you log in, there should be nothing on your dock. And it's important to me that my dock be clean, just as a preference thing.

Comment: I do not use `dash-to-dock` (I prefer `dash-to-panel`), so I cannot test this. But, I think you can report the bug at: https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/development.html